# probability of selecting candidates from a pool of applicants

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[image]

I'm trying to solve this problem, but am stuck finding the probability in part a.

First, I believe there is a total of $n!$ possible outcomes for each of the n colleges (hence $n * n!$ total possibilities).

Since there are n colleges and n students, each college must pick a distinct student. Hence I thought that

> College 1 has student 1 ( n C 1 ) chosen, and has (n-1)! permutations for arranging the rest of students.

> College 2 has student 2 ( n-1 C 1) chosen, and has (n-1)! permutations.

> ...

> College n has student n ( n - (n-1) C 1 = 1 C 1) chosen, and has (n-1)! permutations.

Hence overall, the colleges have n*(n-1)*...*1 * (n-1)! = n! (n-1)! possible choices of selecting distinct n students.
But this is clearly larger than the total possible outcome I had calculated earlier, and I was wondering where I went wrong. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but have a few small mathematical errors.

In your computation of total possible outcomes, it should be $(n!)^n$, rather than $n \cdot n!$.

In your computation of the desired outcomes, it should be $n! ((n-1)!)^n$, rather than $n! (n-1)!$.

---

Note that you can simplify the problem by supposing each college selects a single student at random to admit. You can ignore their rankings of the remaining students; in your approach, this simplification corresponds to the cancellation of $((n-1)!)^n$ in your numerator and denominator.